# dynamically change url parameters while calling API

Tags: javascript

I want to call an API a number of times in one request. The aim is to dynamically change the date parameters for each request so that i get data for different days at once.

I saw the following code while I was researching. It stores my data for one request:

```
var myjson;
$.getJSON("http://127.0.0.1:8080/horizon-update", function(json){
    myjson = json;
});
```

But how can I make multiple calls with different date parameters while storing different outputs as json from the API?

Comment: `with different date parameters` - date parameters? don't see ANY parameters in the code you posted

Comment: @JaromandaX is it possible to do this? Maybe you can assist with the thinking process of how to do it along with some documentation. Then maybe i can try to code something meaningful.

Comment: I already posted an answer ... making some assumptions of course

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply create a function that accepts an argument, and use the argument two-fold - one for the request, and also to "store" the result

```
var myData = {};
function getDate(date) {
    $.getJSON("http://127.0.0.1:8080/horizon-update?date="+date, function(data){
        myData[date] = data;
    });
}
getDate('date1');
getDate('date2');
getDate('date3');
```

None of this code, however, takes into consideration the asynchronous nature of the request, but neither does the code in the question

Note: I changed the name of the result object in the callback and the var the result is stored in to reflect the fact that it **is not JSON** - the returned data may be, but jQuery.getJSON returns the parsed JSON as a plain ol' javascript object

You're more likely to want something like this though

```
function getDate(date) {
    return $.getJSON("http://127.0.0.1:8080/horizon-update?date="+date);
}
$.when(getDate('date1'), getDate('date2'), getDate('date3'))
.then(function(result1, result2, result3) {
    // the results are in
})
```

Of course, if the number of calls is "dynamic", it's a little more complex (especially with jQuery.when)

```
function getDate(date) {
    return $.getJSON("http://127.0.0.1:8080/horizon-update?date="+date);
}
var dates = ['date1', 'date2', 'date3'];
$.when.apply($, dates.map(function(date) {
    return getDate(date);
}).then(function() {
    // the results are in arguments[]

})
```

> Now, as jQuery.getJSON returns a `thenable` (promise) - you can use `Promise.all` to make the code that much easier - if you wish to support IE, you'll need a [Promise polyfill](https://github.com/jakearchibald/es6-promise/) - this one is the one linked to in [MDN Promise docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) - but there are literally dozens of options

```
function getDate(date) {
    return $.getJSON("http://127.0.0.1:8080/horizon-update?date="+date);
}
var dates = ['date1', 'date2', 'date3'];
Promise.all(dates.map(function(date) {
    return getDate(date);
}).then(function(results) {
    // results is an array of the results - in the same order as the dates array
})
```

Comment: Showing something that uses `Promise.all` might be useful.

Comment: Yes, was tossing up using native promises

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use

```
jquery.each(array,callback)
callback is a function(integer indexOfArray,object value)
or function(String propertyName,object value)
```

First you can construct the entire url with date parameter ,then put them into the array.  then apply the same function for each url parameter
And use jquery.each() method，